# DNS Configuration issues

Tags: domain-name-system

I recently started using entrydns.net as my domain's DNS Manager. I have hosting from another webhost and they provided me with

```
NS: ns01.domain.com, ns02.domain.com
A : x.x.x.x
```

Now in my domain (mydomain.com), I set the following NS Records:

```
ns1.entrydns.net, ns2.entrydns.net, ns3.entrydns.net
```

Now, in entrydns.net I set up the following only :

```
NS : ns01.domain.com, ns02.domain.com
A : x.x.x.x
```

Then I checked with Pingdom DNS Checker and found some strange errors. Can you please suggest ways to correct the problem.

http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/?domain=srijit.com

1. Superfluous name server listed at parent: ns1.entrydns.net
2. Superfluous name server listed at parent: ns2.entrydns.net
3. Superfluous name server listed at parent: ns3.entrydns.net
4. Total parent/child glue mismatch.
5. Name server ns01.000webhost.com (31.170.167.6) does not answer queries over TCP.
6. 2 different serials found.
7. different SOA records found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting `NS` records within your zone on `entrydns.net`, you're performing a delegation from their servers. This confuses things a bit because the `entrydns.net` nameservers consider themselves authoritative for the domain. Remove the `NS` records pointing to the other nameservers.

You should be hosting these zones exclusively on `entrydns.net` and making your changes there. If you want them to get the data from a different source (i.e. `ns01.000webhost.com.`), this should be accomplished with zone transfers.

---

Extra info:

```
# dig +norecurse @ns1.entrydns.net. srijit.com A | awk '{print "    " $0}'

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> +norecurse @ns1.entrydns.net. srijit.com A
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 59730
;; flags: qr aa; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;srijit.com.                        IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
srijit.com.         3600    IN      A       31.170.160.100

;; Query time: 111 msec
;; SERVER: 213.229.74.106#53(213.229.74.106)
;; WHEN: Sat Mar  2 14:00:59 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 44
```

If this nameserver didn't consider itself authoritative, it should be serving up an `AUTHORITY` section with no `ANSWER` to perform a delegation. Yet if we look at the NS records it returns...

```
# dig +norecurse @ns1.entrydns.net. srijit.com NS | awk '{print "    " $0}'

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> +norecurse @ns1.entrydns.net. srijit.com NS
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 33331
;; flags: qr aa; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;srijit.com.                        IN      NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
srijit.com.         3600    IN      NS      ns01.000webhost.com.
srijit.com.         3600    IN      NS      ns02.000webhost.com.

;; Query time: 113 msec
;; SERVER: 213.229.74.106#53(213.229.74.106)
;; WHEN: Sat Mar  2 14:00:41 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 77
```

...we're being sent to different nameservers entirely.

Comment: While I agree, in short remove the NS entries of ns01. & ns02 from entrydns.

Comment: It was in the first paragraph intentionally. Added a linebreak.

Comment: I got your point  but if I remove ns01.domain.com and ns02.domain.com which are the ns of my hosting provider, then i think i will not be able to browse my website.

Comment: Now, I added ns1.entrydns.com, ns2.entrydns.com, ns3.entrydns.com as NS in entrydns domain settings. After this domain delegation is green.
But I still get the following errors :

1. Name server ns01.000webhost.com (31.170.167.6) does not answer queries over TCP.
2. 2 different serials found.
3. 2 different SOA records found.

Comment: You're still getting the serial number errors because you did not remove the extra NS records. You should only list `NS` records that all contain the same "version" of the zone, and that data should be replicated automatically somehow. (not copied by hand) You need to do one of these things: 1) use entrydns exclusively, 2) log in to your DNS registrar, point the DNS servers to 000webhost and use them exclusively, or 3) continue to use all five nameservers, but set up automatic zone transfers between them. The TCP error means UDP is blocked but TCP isn't; probably something you can't fix.

Comment: @Andrew B : If i use entrydns exclusively then i will not be able to use my hosts NS.
If i use only my host's NS, then I have some limitations like i cannot add extra CNAMES, mx ets.

Can you guide me how to set up Automatic Zone Transfers?

Comment: I can't, because it depends on how zone transfers are implemented using these web interfaces. You can get away with this setup as long as you're *very carefully* keeping everything up to date, but it's not recommended. Do note that you don't *need* your web host's DNS servers unless they are providing some kind of service that automatically updates records for you. The benefits of having that many nameservers isn't as great if they're not automatically kept in sync.

Comment: My bad, I missed your answer.  Andrew is 100% correct.